# How do I get a web page element using a .querySelector()? Webdriver-io

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, webdriver-io

Within Webdriver-io tests, I need to get a web page element using .querySelector()

This code:

```
a = browser.executeScript('window.document.querySelector("div.my_diagram_div canvas")', [])
console.log('a = ', await a)
```

outputs the following output:

```
a =  { 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'ELEMENT-40' }
```

It's not an element object, I can't work with it any further. How do I get the web page element object?

P.S. In the browser console, the code returns the correct result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ever you get in console is just a representation of element, its not the actual output.

if you want that html tag use

Within Webdriver-io tests, I need to get a web page element using .querySelector()

use:

```
a = browser.executeScript('window.document.querySelector("div.my_diagram_div canvas").outerHTML', [])
console.log('a = ', await a)
```

or

```
a = await $('div.my_diagram_div canvas')
console.log('a = ', await a.getProperty("outerHTML"))
```

**UPDATE**

If you need the element object just use

```
   a = await browser.executeScript('window.document.querySelector("div.my_diagram_div canvas")', [])
   elm=    await $(a)
   await elm.getWindowRect()
```

also in this case yo udon't need executescript

```
   elm=    await $('div.my_diagram_div canvas')
   await elm.getWindowRect()
```

Comment: .outerHTML returns a string, not an object. I need to get an element object in order to execute the method obj.getBoundingClientRect(), so .outerHTML is not appropriate.

Comment: why are you using queryselector instead of webdriverio selectors and https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver/#getwindowrect

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. The error appears: `TypeError: elm.getwindowrect is not a function.`

The exact same error appears when using **.getBoundingClientRect()** outside of **browser.executeScript()**

Comment: use await elm.getwindowrect()

Comment: theere is no webdrverio method as getBoundingClientRect ,

Comment: Hallelujah, elm.getWindowRect() method worked! Thank you so much! Just please edit your answer because it is important to be case sensitive and use elm.getWindowRect() and not elm.getwindowrect()

Comment: updated , and for this entire use case you don't need browser.execute